# Google index: robots.txt to stop wp uploads indexing

Tags: wordpress, indexing, seo, robots.txt

I have a Wordpress site that is being indexed by google, but google is picking up images as search results - ie if I do site:mysite.com I see loads of results which, when clicked on, just go to images from wp-content/uploads/

How do I stop these from coming up in search results, whilst still allowing them in google images?

I've made changes to my robots.txt so the first bit reads:

```
User-agent:*
Noindex: /product-tag/*
Noindex: /product-tag/
Noindex: /wp-content/uploads/*
Noindex: /forum/profile/*
Noindex: /my-account/*
Noindex: /my-account/
Noindex: /?s=*
Noindex: /tag/*

Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/*
Disallow: /product-tag/*
Disallow: /product-tag/
Disallow: /forum/profile/*
Disallow: /my-account/*
Disallow: /my-account/
Disallow: /?s=*
Disallow: /tag/*

Allow: /shop/*
Allow: /product-category/*

User-agent: Googlebot-image
Allow: /
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

I guess my question is, is this ok or am I doing something wrong? If it is right, how do I get google to realize that some results shouldn't be in the index any more?

I'm aware that I can request removal of pages individually but there is a large amount so I'd rather re-index my entire site if that's the right way to go.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*.gif$
Disallow: /*.png$
```

Error is in your code, you allowed Googlebot-image to index your images

```
User-agent: Googlebot-image
Allow: /
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

Refer this : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en